# Apache forward all requests to a specific static file

Tags: apache, http, testing, request, forward

I am trying to **forward** (not redirect !) all http requests on my virtual host to a static file.

I would like to fake request by responding same data.

All example that I found redirect me to the static page, I would like to keep my URL in the browser (no 301,302,.. status code) !

How to do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a textbook example of AliasMatch in mod_alias:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#aliasmatch

For example:

AliasMatch .* /usr/local/apache/my_static_file.html